# How can I print an answer to the Two Sum leetcode problem?

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python and I would like some help with printing an answer. Using the print() function, how could I actually print an answer if I use a list of around a thousand numbers.

```
def twoSum(self, nums: list[int], target: int) -> list[int]:
        dictionary = {}
        answer = []
        
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            secondNumber = target-nums[i]
            if(secondNumber in dictionary.keys()):
                secondIndex = nums.index(secondNumber)
                if(i != secondIndex):
                    return sorted([i, secondIndex])
                
            dictionary.update({nums[i]: i})
```

Comment: Please add an example of the expected output format.

Comment: @Markus , it seems like this is the TwoSum problem on Leetcode. [This](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/) is the link :)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @Neurocity. Still I don’t understand what is asked. This function returns one pair of indices, if a solution is found. So why are you asking about thousands of numbers?

Answer (score 0):

You can print the first 10 in your answer using Slices (e.g., `answer[:10]`). By the way, remember to return the answer list!